# How to override a function that returns a task

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, overriding

I have the following fucntion:

```
public override Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
{
    return base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, isPersistent, shouldLockout);
}
```

I want to modify it to something like this:

```
public override Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
{
    var result = base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, isPersistent, shouldLockout);

    //If status was successful do some thing here
    if(result =  success)
    {
       //update last logged in time.
    }

    //Lastly return the result
    return result;
}
```

Now I want to modify what the function does.

I want to execute the base task, and then use the result from it to do something in my overriding function?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do so by adding the `async` keyword to the method, and awaiting the base operation:

```
public async override Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
{
    var result = await base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, isPersistent, shouldLockout);

    // Check result
    return result;
}
```

Because the provided base call returns a `Task<T>` which is awaitable, you can await it's asynchronous completion using `async-await`.

Note this means you would have to go "async all the way" and make sure the calls are properly awaited throughout the callstack.

More on `async-await` can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: then do i just return result at the end?

Comment: Yes. That fact that you've used `await` inside your method call, makes the compiler transform the operation into a state-machine which generates a `Task`. When you `return result`, that result is actually wrapped as a `Task<SignInStatus>`

Comment: I get a stackoverflow exception when adding async and await to  overriding method that returns a task..

Comment: @Bartosz Do ask a new question with the involved details.

Comment: I did - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50316056/stackoverflow-exception-when-overriding-a-task-returning-method-when-adding-asyn