# StackOverflow exception when overriding a Task returning method when adding async

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, asp.net-identity, overriding

I have a custom user manager class (ASP .NET Identity). I want to override the FindByIdMethod, so that it automatically loads the role names for the user model. This is the only method I am overriding. I am using `Microsoft.Identity` nuget packages version 2.2.1, Asp.Net Framework.

However, the code below throws a StackOverflow exception - at `await base.FindByIdAsync(userId);`

```
 public class MyUserManager : UserManager<MyUser>, IMyUserManager
 {
    public override async Task<MyUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        var user = await base.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        user.RoleNames = await this.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
        return user;
    }
 }
```

When I try similar code without adding 'async' to the overriden signature it works OK - however, I cannot load my role names in this method:

```
public override Task<MyUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
{
    var userTask = base.FindByIdAsync(userId); //no errors in this approach
    return userTask; //but also no custom behaviour 
}
```

I suspect maybe the IMyUserManager might be problematic, but I need it for the IOC/DI. This was an autogenerated interface, so it has all the public members of the UserManager class.

The user class:

```
public class MyUser: IdentityUser
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActivated { get; set; }
    public bool MustChangePassword { get; set; }
    public IList<string> RoleNames { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Exception details: 
[image]

Call stack (TelimenaUserManager = MyUserManager, I simplified the name)

[image]

UPDATE:

Thanks to Henk's suggestions in the comments, I see that recursion happens in the GetRolesAsync method...
[image]

Comment: Is that the only method you override, or there are others?

Comment: Just to be sure - did you check `RoleNames` ?  Post (parts of) MyUser to make sure. Also for any other method you overrode. (GetRolesAsync?)

Comment: @HenkHolterman - this is the only overrdien method. And MyUser is very simple, see updpated question

Comment: Can you please add the stack trace?

Comment: I'm a little confused over `GetRolesAsync(user.Id)` , shouldn't that be `GetRolesAsync(user)` ? And to resolve that difference there could be a `FindByIdAsync()` hiding somewhere. Causing an SO.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - added

Comment: Als tell us about all relevant versions, there have been many editions of the Id fx.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I am using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity nugets, version 2.2.1. And I only see `GetRolesAsync(string userId)`...

Comment: ASp.NET has two major flavours nowadays: Core and Framework. Always mention which one.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - good point - framework!

Comment: See if you can find the source for GetRolesAsync(string userId), I think that's where your recursion happens.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - seems you were right, see the updated question

Comment: Then you also have your answer, when you can mimic that `userRolesStore.GetRolesAsync()` call.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I am posting the working code.

I had to cast the current 'IUserStore' to be the 'IUserRoleStore' (Both generic arguments are needed!).

Then get the roles based on the user instance (which avoids the recursion of 'Finding the user')

```
 public override async Task<MyUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
        {
            var user = await base.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            var roleStore = this.Store as IUserRoleStore<MyUser, string>;
            user.RoleNames = await roleStore.GetRolesAsync(user);
            return user;
        }
```

Thanks @HenkHolterman!